# Writing some object oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

Here I dynamically create a product form.

```
<?php 
//Prints out some form x times
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){productform($i);}

function productform($i){
print'<form><p id="res'.$i.'">
 <input type="text" class="date start" name="datumbegin" />
 <input type="text" class="time start" name="tijdbegin"/>
 <input type="text" class="date end" name="datumeind"/>
</p></form>';}
?>
```

How can I make the following JavaScript work OOP without my PHP?

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
print"
    <script>
        $('#res".$i.".time').timepicker({
            'disableTimeRanges':[['00:00','00:00'],['24:00','24:00']],
            'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
            'disableTextInput':true,
            'show2400':true,
            'step':30,
            'showDuration':true,
            'timeFormat':'H:i'
        });

        $('#res".$i.".date').datepicker({
            'disableTextInput':true,
            'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
            'format':'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'autoclose':true
        });

            $('#res".$i."').datepair();
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Without PHP, you have to put it in an HTML file or put it directly in a developer's console of a browser. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/. But your example seems to be using DOM elements - so you have to use an HTML file to put your script in - then open the HTML file in a browser.

Comment: You don't need OOP. Just put that second `for` loop in your JavaScript instead of your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In your page, replace the PHP code with the JavaScript code snippet below.

```
<script>
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
   $('#res' + i + '.time').timepicker({
        'disableTimeRanges':[['00:00','00:00'],['24:00','24:00']],
        'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
        'disableTextInput':true,
        'show2400':true,
        'step':30,
        'showDuration':true,
        'timeFormat':'H:i'
    });

    $('#res' +  i + '.date').datepicker({
        'disableTextInput':true,
        'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
        'format':'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose':true
    });

    $('#res' + i).datepair();
)
</script>
```